# Как создать timeout Observable из события?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, rxjs, timeout

Моя задача - остановить таймер по двойному нажатию кнопки "wait". Это нужно сделать используя кастомный observable со своим timeout. Timeout нужен, так как задание гласит что между нажатиями должно пройти не больше 300 милисекунд. Если пройдет больше - ничего происходить не должно.
То есть - функция при первом нажатии создает по клику observable, который сам себя завершает, если прошло больше 300 мс, в ином случае он завершает таймер (пересылает false в соответствующую функцию).

Вот код моего метода и он не работает

```
  waitClock(el: ElementRef) {
    const waitObs = el.nativeElement.fromEvent(el, 'click', (observer) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.clickWaitCount = 0;
      }, 300);
    });
    if (this.clickWaitCount >= 2) {
      this.stopWatch(false);
      this.isStarted = false;
      this.hasPaused = true;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
import { fromEvent, interval } from 'rxjs'; 
import { map, buffer, debounceTime, filter, takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

const click$ = fromEvent(document, 'click')

const doubleClick$ = click$.pipe(
  buffer(
    click$.pipe(debounceTime(300))
  ),
  map(list => {
    return list.length;
  }),
  filter(x => x === 2),
)

const $timer = interval(1000).pipe(takeUntil(doubleClick$));

$timer.subscribe(console.log);
```

А если хотите запускать интервал по одной кнопке и останавливать по двойному щелчку по другой кнопке, то я бы сделал так:

```
export class MyTimer implements OnDestroy  {
  click$ = new Subject();

  doubleClick$ = this.click$.pipe(
    buffer(
      this.click$.pipe(debounceTime(300))
    ),
    map(list => {
      return list.length;
    }),
    filter(x => x === 2),
  )

  start$ = new Subject();

  destroy$ = new Subject();

  timer$ = interval(1000).pipe(
    // С помощью этого оператора мы рестартуем таймер
    takeUntil(this.start$),
    // С помощью этооо оператора мы останавливаем таймер при уничтожении компонента чтоб память не текла
    takeUntil(this.destroy$),
    takeUntil(this.doubleClick$)
  );

  start() {
    this.start$.next();
    this.timer$.subscribe(console.log);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroy$.next();
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button (click)="start()">Click to start interval</button>
  <button (click)="click$.next()">Dubble click to stop interval</button>
</div>
```

Я бы на вашем месте не стал использовать `ViewChild` потому что можно обойтись и без него, как видите.

Comment: почеме-то таймер останавливается только на повторный двойной клик

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fekzch?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts вот тут работает как надо, если глянуть консоль

Comment: Но у меня точно так же почти!

Comment: Вот например https://github.com/Not-a-whale/AngularStopWatch/tree/operators